# How does EF7 bootstrap dependency injection (IServiceCollection) if you're not in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm still trying to get my head around what's what with ASP.NET 5 / EF 7.  I'm using DNX projects (.xproj).

`Startup` is used by OWIN/ASP.NET for configuring, loading services, etc.  But it's also used for EF 7 migrations (to set your `DbContextOptions` for example).

My main goal is to know how EF7 (and ASP.NET 5) bootstrap with `Startup` and who's creating the startup class, initializing the DI container, etc.

An example of what I need to do, for context, is that in my xUnit unit tests (which are in their own assembly and reference my data assembly which doesn't have a `Startup` class), I need to `AddDbContext` to set my connection.

I have the sample startup class:

```
namespace Radar.Data
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;

    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<RadarDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is currently in my data assembly and not my unit test assembly.  I tried adding the app setting (I know it's OWIN but I thought I'd give it a shot):

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="owin:appStartup" value="Radar.Data.Startup, Radar.Data" />
</appSettings>
```

The startup class is not getting executed.

I'd really like an understanding of the overall mechanism with `Startup`, who calls it, etc., but for now, I just need an understanding of how EF 7 initializes dependencies/services so that I can properly initialize my unit tests.

**UPDATE**
Here's what I've got in my unit test so far and I thought I had it working at one point:

```
ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
DbContextActivator.ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
serviceCollection.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<RadarDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=SonOfRadar;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"));
```

but now I'm getting `No service for type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.IDbSetInitializer' has been registered` when my `DbContext` is instantiated.  So obviously not getting all the EF services loaded.

If I comment out:

```
DbContextActivator.ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
```

it errors earlier with: `No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.`

Setting `DbContextActivator.ServiceProvider` is the only place in EF7 where I can find a hook to set your own provider.  I'd be just as happy getting an instance of EF7's internal service collection and working with that.  I think I'm going to scour the EF7 unit test code again and see if I'm missing a critical piece.

Comment: you might get some insights by looking at the tests in in EF Identity Framework library https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Test

Comment: @JoeAudette thanks.  Looks like I've got a little more studying to do haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Startup` class is created by `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting` package when you run you web application (see [StartupLoader.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Startup/StartupLoader.cs)).

You can also look onto `WebApplication.Run` method ([WebApplication.Run](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebApplication.cs#L38)) its an entry point to ASP.NET 5 web applications.

DI is initialized in `WebHostBuilder` class ([WebHostBuilder.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L69)) and inside `dnx` in `Bootstrapper` class ([Bootstrapper.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Host/Bootstrapper.cs#L66))

Comment: Thanks.  Those were very useful points in the source.  So how would I, for example, in an xUnit test which is launched via xunit.runner.dnx, access the DI container so that I can get an IServiceCollection and instantiate and call EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.AddDbContext to specify my connection string?

Comment: It doesn't appear that Startup is part of DNX but part of ASP.NET (and somehow EF migrations hack into it?)

Comment: Yes, startup is ASP.NET concept

Comment: And you add EF services via `services.AddEntityFramework()` call https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L71

Comment: Yeah I came across that, see my updated question with my attempt.

Comment: Do `IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
DbContextActivator.ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;` after adding services, not before

Comment: Did that and much success for several instantiations and uses of my DbContext (in the same test run), then got (in the same test run) the "No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services." error.  So very good progress.  Just need to figure out why I'm losing the services.

Comment: Looks like I was running into issues with my other DI container.  This was code I ported over.  I converted my other DI abstraction to use the underlying MS DI (IServiceCollection, IServiceProvider) instead of Ninject and it's all good now.