# How to properly initialize EF7 for xunit tests run with xunit.runner.dnx

Tags: xunit, dnx, entity-framework-core

I have a DNX unit test assembly where I'm testing code that uses EF7.

In a web app, I have the `Startup` class where I can provide a `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method and initialize like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<RadarDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
}
```

Where is the equivalent "hook" for an xunit test running under DNX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNX runner for Xunit never calls Startup.cs. The "hook" you are looking for is either a class fixture or your test class constructor.  (See https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html)

How you choose to initialize EF from there is up to you. You could use dependency injection and follow the `.AddDbContext()` pattern above or you could initialize your DbContext directly. (see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Configuring-a-DbContext which is slightly outdated)

Comment: Thanks Nate.  Perusing the sources, that's the conclusion I've been coming to.  This is the 2nd in a series of 3 questions I've asked trying to figure things out about ASP.NET 5, EF7, and DI and initialization within the two.  The first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028008/how-does-ef7-bootstrap-dependency-injection-iservicecollection-if-youre-not-i, and the second third question which is actually where I'm at in the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167161/default-service-creation-for-asp-net-5-serviceprovider