# Default service creation for ASP.NET 5 ServiceProvider

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm using DNX and the default `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider` for DI.

I am used to Ninject where if I haven't registered a service, it defaults to using the service type as the implementation type, e.g. if I haven't registered `MyService` and I ask the container for an instance of `MyService` (or it's a constructor parameter), it uses `MyService` as the implementation type.

Is there a way to configure `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider` to behave similarly?  I would like it to create a `Transient` instance for anything unregistered.

Comment: Awesome article: http://www.emadashi.com/2015/06/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-5-one-step-deeper/